# How to execute a second program after the first persistent program finishes its initialization using batch commands?

Tags: batch-file

I'm using a batch file to run two different executable programs. I would like the second program to run after the first finishes its initialization and opens a port on my computer.

I'm aware of the *call* and */wait* commands for sequential command ordering, although the first program is a persistent application that opens a port on my computer; therefore, it never "finishes" running. Closing the executable's command prompt closes the port. Due to this behavior, if I use either aforementioned command then the second called program finishes running before the first and causes issues. I realize this explanation is somewhat confusing but if clarification is needed I will give more context. Thanks.

EDIT: Using @shadoe2020's code and removing the condition statement.

```
:: This file starts the mongod.exe and mongo.exe executables.
:: @ECHO OFF

start C:\Users\jacob\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe

:search
tasklist|find "mongod.exe"
TIMEOUT /T 3
GOTO found

:found
start C:\Users\jacob\mongodb\bin\mongo.exe
GOTO end

:end
PAUSE
```

Comment: Don't include answers in question posts, post answer as answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:: This file starts the mongod.exe and mongo.exe executables.
:: @ECHO OFF

start C:\Users\jacob\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe

:search
ver > nul
tasklist|find "mongod.exe"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 GOTO :found
TIMEOUT /T 5
GOTO search

:found
start C:\Users\jacob\mongodb\bin\mongo.exe
GOTO end

:end
PAUSE
```

how about checking for the process you could even do a timeout after it finds the process say 20 seconds to allow program 1 to connect to whatever you're connecting to.

Comment: I'll implement what you've provided into my batch file. I'm fairly new to both Stack Overflow and creating batch files, so I'll try to provide some feedback with my progress.

Comment: Good luck! Keep us posted :)

Comment: [Here's](http://collabedit.com/h23ek) what I have based on your commands. I had to research a few things about the batch commands! It doesn't work as intended :(

Comment: It shows up as mongod.exe, although omitting the if statement makes things work. Thanks! Also, did I just edit your comment? If so, it wasn't a conscious decision haha, my bad.

Comment: Under search I added this "ver > nul"

Because that resets the error level. I think what was happening is it was looking for the task before it actually existed, and was setting the error level and getting stuck in a loop. This should fix that. You should be all set now.

Comment: Yep, appending this to my code makes everything work as intended. Thanks.